# R - ggplot2 - boxplots are too big

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to ggplot (aka ggplot2) and have noticed that for some reason it always makes my boxplots so large that a single box dominates the entire plot. The plot below was generated from the ToothGrowth dataset using the following code:

```
bp = ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, color = dose)) + geom_boxplot() + theme(legend.position = "none")
bp
```

[image: Huge Boxplot]

In case you haven't got the ToothGrowth dataset for some reason (its in the library "datasets"), the variables len and dose are both numeric. **len** has three discreet values, (0.5, 1.0, 2.0) while **dose** is continuous from approximately 4-30. I expect my boxplot to show three different boxes for the three discreet values of **len**

I suspect this is caused by some weird graphics settings but I have no idea where to begin my search. Has anyone else run into this kind of problem?

Comment: The `width` parameter controls how wide the boxes are relative to the rest of the plot. `ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=dose)) + geom_boxplot(width=0.2)`.

Comment: This "color = dose"  makes me assume that you're trying to plot 3 boxplots of **dose** (not len)...is that the case?

Comment: Or, for a single boxplot (not grouped by dose in this case): `ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x="", y=len)) + geom_boxplot(width=0.5) + labs(x="")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to plot for each "level" of dose one boxplot.
That could be done converting into a factor your `x` within the `ggplot2` call.

Here's how to:

```
bp = ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=factor(dose), y=len, color = dose)) + geom_boxplot() + theme(legend.position = "none")
bp
```

And here's the plot

[image]

---

Another option is to use the group aesthetic, which allows you to keep the x axis on your original scale (instead of assuming a 1 unit difference between each level if you use `factor()`). In this case they're pretty similar, but could be important for other uses.

```
bp = ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, color = dose, group = dose)) + geom_boxplot() + theme(legend.position = "none")
bp
```

[image]

Comment: You also could use the group aesthetic ie `aes(x = dose, y = len, color = dose, group = dose)` This will maintain the different distances between 0.5 and 1, vs 1 and 2 if that is important for your graph.